# Spoilers look like blockquotes in Suggested Edits preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, markdown, spoilers

I [suggested an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/47562) in which I changed the blockquote markup (`>`) to the spoiler markup (`>!`). However, in the Suggested Edits preview (the "rendered output" tab) it still looks like a blockquote:

[image: freehand circles ftw]

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one and was a bit offput. The spoiler works, though, if you hover on and then off again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with animuson that it shouldn't be completely hidden, but I also agree with you that it'd be nice to have spoilers look different from normal blockquotes.

So I've settled on this: Spoilers in diffs still fade out like in normal question/answer views, but not to complete transparency. With that, from the next build on, it will look like this:

[image: screenshot of a diff with the new spoiler styling applied]

(That's a screenshot of a revision diff, but it'll be the same in suggested edit previews.)

Answer (score 7):

I'd argue that this rendering is beneficial. Rendering them as normal spoilers with hidden text is dangerous, as it allows users to insert new text into a block of hidden text that users may potentially not notice while reviewing. We don't want to end up with spam or completely different text in a spoiler simply because it's not shown by default while reviewing and no one thought to hover over it before accepting a change they *thought* merely changed a blockquote to a spoiler.

This functions the exact same way in the revision history. Text within spoilers is not hidden if it's been modified. Anything that was changed, regardless of whether it was in a spoiler or not, should be blatantly obvious when reviewing or viewing changes to a post; not hidden from view.